# Removing last two chars from each line in a text file

Tags: linux

How do I remove the last two chars from each line in a text file using just Linux commands?

Also my file seems to have weird ^A delimiters in it. What char does ^A correspond to?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
sed 's/..$//' filename.txt
```

Comment: What if one wants to remove the last 1232 characters?

Comment: Got it: `sed 's/.\{1232\}$//' filename`

Answer (score 3):

Second BenV's answer. However you can make sure that you only remove ^A by:

```
sed 's/^A^A$//' <file>
```

In addition to that, to find out what ^A is, I did the following:

```
% echo -n '^A' |od -x
0000000 0001
0000001

% ascii 0x01
ASCII 0/1 is decimal 001, hex 01, octal 001, bits 00000001: called ^A, SOH
Official name: Start Of Heading
```

(wanted to add as a comment but it doesn't do quoting properly)

Comment: Note that you need to type Ctrl-A, not a literal ^ and a literal A.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use awk

```
awk '{sub(/..$/,"")}1' file
```

you can also use the shell

```
while read -r line; do echo ${line:0:(${#line}-2)}; done<file
```

however if you are talking about getting rid of DOS newlines (ie \r\n), you can use `dos2unix` command

Comment: i like that you have provided for variations on a theme but i think `sed` is perhaps the most suitable